# Rails multiple support for Latin, Dutch, etc

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

We have our app up and running it's quite simple yet few of our international friends are having issues getting their tweets into our DB in their language. Anything other then English comes out either ????? Or funky.

I've looked into few possible options but having a hard time understanding the right approach.

Our general function is grabbing a tweet from their twitter and store it's content into a column in table on our DB.

Do we write a custom controller or model to convert or have to setup different dB's?

Answer (score 0):

Use i18n http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Additionally, make sure your DB is set up to support the characters in the languages you're using. For example, MySql's `utf8` mode doesn't actually support all utf8 characters; you'd have to use `utf8mb4` for that.

Comment: I'm not looking to provide all app content in different languages, however I think I do have to convert my current MySQL DB from utf8 to utf8mb4 like you said. Not sure if that's the only thing I have to do to display them properly after from DB.